# ssh multiple clients

Tags: ssh, connection, client

Hi I am new to ssh server but I have successfully been running it on other Ubuntu 12.04 computers.

The latest computer I set up with openssh-server only seems to allow one shared connection between all the clients. I never had this problem before with the other computers and I checked the config files are the same as other computers that allow multiple connections.

Also this openssh server shows a bar at the bottom of all the clients ssh terminal windows displaying the Ubuntu version, time of connection, date, cpu.

I don't have this on other setups and have tried reinstalling openssh-server.

What program or option is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you've installed `byobu`.

From the package description:

```
Description-en: powerful, text based window manager and shell multiplexer
 Byobu is Ubuntu's text-based window manager based on GNU Screen.
 Using Byobu, you can quickly create and move between different windows
 over a single SSH connection or TTY terminal, monitor dozens of important
 statistics about your system, detach and reattach to sessions later
 while your programs continue to run in the background.
```

All logins to your server get automatically attached to the same byobu session, so it seems that only 1 user is allowed to log in.

You can disable the automatic usage via issuing.

```
byobu-disable
```

on the command line. You might have to restart the ssh server, or even reboot for it to take effect.

If it's not byobu, perhaps it's `screen` or `tmux`, which do the same.